# Convert string for double a file with mixed text and numbers?

Tags: c#

The exercise asks you to print the name of the employees with salary greater than 1800.00

The exercise asks you to print the name of the employees with salary greater than 1800.00.

Open date with *notepad + +*

Column 54-107 is the name of the client.
Column 156-163 is employee salaries (Those with with 000 salary is to disrupt it).

I can not convert the share of wages could someone help me?

#### Code Program

```
double salconv =0;;
string linha, salario="";
string[] maior = new string[100]; 
       
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\BRENOLL\Videos\data.txt");
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    linha = sr.ReadLine();
    string nomes = linha.Substring(53, 52);
    salario = sr.ReadLine();
    salconv = Double.Parse(salario.Substring(156, 6));

    Console.WriteLine(salconv);
}
           
sr.Close();
              
Console.ReadKey();`
```

---

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1h5yjp8u5halrlw/25251.jpg)

[file dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiugtmdeo1vfd83/data.txt)

Comment: What is the string value that you want to parse and what is your `CurrentCulture`? An example would be nice.

Comment: And what output are you currently getting?

Comment: I think you got the indexing wrong and need to substract 1 from all start indices, as notepad probably counts from 1

Comment: You are reading a line twice per each loop cycle: `linha = sr.ReadLine();` and `salario = sr.ReadLine();`. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

I've run your sample data using your code. It breaks at last line. You are trying to parse a string full of white space `"     "`.

One workaround would be to use `TryParse` method instead. But then if your data are incorrect they will be ignored.

```
double salconv = 0; ;
string linha, salario = "";
string[] maior = new string[100];

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\pw\Downloads\data.txt");
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    linha = sr.ReadLine();
    string nomes = linha.Substring(53, 52);
    salario = sr.ReadLine();

    if (Double.TryParse(salario.Substring(156, 6), out salconv))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(salconv);
    }
}

sr.Close();

Console.ReadKey();
```

Alos, consider wrapping your `StreamReader` with a `using` statement.